# How to Build ExpoKit Apk

Tags: react-native, expo

when i follow Expo Detached official Document [Document](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach)

then Expo Detached successfully After that i Follow this step

1. Publish Script bundle using XDE
2. Build Apk using Gradle As Describe [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

After that APK generate Successfully When i install this APK in physical device Then Blue Screen appear with "could not load app. Are You sure XDE or exp is running "

Where is i wrong

Thanks in Advance